# c# check textbox for unique values

Tags: c#, count, duplicates, textbox, distinct

I have a textbox where user inputs values, each one in a new row, now i want to check if those input values are unique, but looks like it does not work if duplicated value is a last value, don't know why. Any tips?
Lets say it is:

```
1
2
3
3
```

It will not work, but

```
1
2
3
3
5
```

Will work and show an error as duplicate

Here is a code i use:
First I split textbox into array of strings

```
     string[] linesValues = textBoxValues.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

then check for duplicates and show error

```
if (linesValues.Distinct().Count() != linesValues.Count()) { MessageBox.Show("Question values must be unique!", "Duplicated values found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); return; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest *processing* the values: removing empty / all whitespaces strings,  *leading* and *trailing* spaces at least (note, that `"3 " != " 3" != "3"`):

1. `new Char[] { '\n', '\r' }` note `\r` can appear as a new line; let's be on the safer side of the road
2. `.Where(item => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))` we don't want all whitespaces line (empty lines included) like `"  "`
3. `item => item.Trim()` questions processing; let `"3"` be equal to `"3 "`

**Code:**

```
string[] linesValues = textBoxValues
  .Text
  .Split(new Char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 
  .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
  .Select(item => item.Trim())
  .ToArray();
```

and then check as you do

```
using System.Linq;

...

if (linesValues.Distinct().Count() != linesValues.Count()) { 
  MessageBox.Show("Question values must be unique!", 
                  "Duplicated values found", 
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                   MessageBoxIcon.Error); 

  return; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the trick, works like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] linesValues = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 };

            if (AnyDuplicate(linesValues))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Question values must be unique!", "Duplicated values found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

        }  

  private bool AnyDuplicate(int[] numbers)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (numbers[i] == numbers[j])
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
```